# CMake target does not build when its dependency target builds

Tags: cmake

In a java project, there are multiple packages, each gets build into corresponding jar file. Each of these packages is one target in CMake. And as higher level packages depend of lower level ones, I have `add_dependencies` between them.

The `add_dependencies` ensures that lower level packages are built before the higher level ones - This works, even when building with `make -j8`.

However, when files of a lower level package changes, it builds just its corresponding package and not the ones which uses it. I thought `add_dependencies` will also ensure that if one dependency is out of date, it will build the dependency as well as the dependent target. This does not happen.

Here is a minimal but complete example of the setup:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Target TA (src/ta/CMakeLists.txt)
------------------------------------------------------------
add_custom_target(TA DEPENDS TA.jar)
                                                 
# Build jar file
add_custom_command(OUTPUT TA.jar
     DEPENDS ${TA_CLASS_FILES}
     COMMAND <command to pack class files into a jar file>
     COMMENT "Creating TA.jar.."
)

# Generate java class files
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${TA_CLASS_FILES})
     DEPENDS ta.java
     COMMAND <command to compile source files>
     COMMENT "Compiling TA.."
)

------------------------------------------------------------
Target TB (src/tb/CMakeLists.txt)
------------------------------------------------------------
add_custom_target(TB DEPENDS TB.jar)

# Build jar file
add_custom_command(OUTPUT TB.jar
     DEPENDS ${TB_CLASS_FILES}
     COMMAND <command to pack class files into a jar file>
     COMMENT "Creating TB.jar.."
)

# Generate java class files
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${TB_CLASS_FILES})
     DEPENDS tb.java
     COMMAND <command to compile source files>
     COMMENT "Compiling TB.."
)

# TB uses TA class files so, TA must be build before TB.
add_dependencies(TB TA)
```

If I change `ta.java` then TA (and `ta.jar`) gets built, but TB which depends on TA does not update.

```
$ cd build
$ touch ../src/ta/ta.java
$ make
[   6%] Compiling TA..
[  13%] Creating TA.jar..
[  13%] Built target TA
[ 100%] Built target TB
$
```

Please help me understand why `add_dependencies` does not ensure that the child dependencies are updated when one of its parent updated.

PS: The solution I found is to add `ta.jar` to `DEPENDS` in the last `add_custom_command` of TB target i.e `DEPENDS tb.java ta.jar`. But still not sure why the jar need to be explicitly mentioned.

Comment: Why not use CMake's built in Java support? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/UseJava.html

Comment: @AlexReinking I tried it first, but older versions (version < 3.21) have various limitations, mainly there is little control where resource files are put. I tried workarounds but in the end I wrote a custom script.

Comment: @ArjobMukherjee - cool, good to know you tried it. CMake's features are not all well known or discoverable, so l I thought I'd ask. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add_dependencies` is about *ordering* not rebuilding. `TA` will be built *before* `TB`

```
[  13%] Built target TA
[ 100%] Built target TB
```

If you want to rebuild, you have to `DEPENDS` on output files. For example:

```
# Build jar file
add_custom_command(
     OUTPUT TA.jar
     DEPENDS ${TA_CLASS_FILES
     COMMAND <command to pack class files into a jar file
     COMMENT "Creating TA.jar.."
)
# Build jar file
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT TB.jar
    DEPENDS ${TB_CLASS_FILES} TA.jar
    COMMAND <command to pack class files into a jar file>
    COMMENT "Creating TB.jar.."                                          
)
```

The way it is done for C++, is that compiler *outputs a list of file dependencies* for every compiled file, which is then read by CMake generated build system. I do not know if such feature is available for Java.

Comment: Thanks. Works. I just wonder why the CMake documentation does not mention/explain this better.